# flash builder, How can I release sound and image object?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

In "abc.mxml"
I created image and sound object like below, and assigned dynamically real data.

```
<s:Image id="imgGoodJob" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" 
         scaleMode="stretch" visible="false" click="onGoodJobClicked()" />
<mm:Sound2 id="sndEndingBgm" />
```

and I release that on memory in "onDeActive()" function, using below codes

```
imgGoodJob = null;
sndEndingBgm = null;
flash.system.System.gc();
```

but, When I watched the memory usage in profiling, that memory doesn't deallocated! 
I don't know what is happening..
Is there another correct method to deallocate object on the memory?

Please let me know that!

- Additionally, in profiling "Vector.<*>" having almost half of memory usage. how can i release this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer.

There are some played and not stopped animations before setting to "null" and calling gc();

After stop all animation gc() works well :)